# How Data Compression relates to Estimating Distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, data-compression

I recently read this paper [Mahoney, 1999](https://cs.fit.edu/%7Emmahoney/poster.pdf).
And encountered this line,

> optimal compression of a probabilistic language L with unknown distribution (such as English) using an estimated distribution M (an encoding of length −log2 M(x) bits for each string x) is M = L, by the discrete channel capacity theorem.

Can you please explain what this means and what is the relation between data compression and estimation of distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have a random source $X$, and we wish to encode many independent samples $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ taken from $X$. An *compression scheme* is an algorithm that converts $n$ samples of $X$ to a binary string in a reversible way. Shannon [showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) that the optimal compression scheme produces binary strings of length roughly $nH(X)$, where $H(X)$ is the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of $X$.

In practice, we may have access to $X$ but might not know its distribution exactly. What we can do is to estimate its distribution as $Y$, and then use an optimal compression for $Y$. This will produce binary strings of length roughly $n(H(X) + D(X\|Y))$, where $D(X\|Y)$ is the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) (called cross-entropy by Mahoney). We have $D(X\|Y) \geq 0$, with equality only when $Y = X$. Thus optimal compression requires knowing the distribution of the source exactly.